%localappdata% and echo %localappdata% returns two different directories
I'm having some issues with Windows 10.  After fixing my temp INET folder which somehow was pointing at a different account, I've now found an odd issue.
If I type echo %localappdata% in CMD, it gives me my correct folder.
However, if I simply type "%localappdata% I get an error that states the folder is not recognized as a command. The listed folder is for the wrong account (a very old one I no longer use).
Where is CMD getting this 2nd environment variable from and how do I fix it?
(same goes for %appdata% too!)

Can you attach some screenshots?

I’m voting to close this question because the user mistyped a command, forgetting to quote a  name with spaces (see comment to answer).

In CMD, if you want to displays the variable or some text, you must use Echo command.
more info Echo /? in CMD.
echo %localappdata%
echo %appdata%

You cannot directly input it without Echo to read the output.
You can check All Environment Variables by type SET in CMD.

just figured I'm being a bit thick!   cmd is taking the space in my new username as the end of the command, so I'm just getting an error message to that bit!  I've been troubleshooting issues with office and onedrive and nothing is making sense, so I'm starting to clutch at straws!

yeah, as much as they pretend otherwise, spaces in file paths will always cause needless pain. avoid them at all reasonable costs.
